# Add folder with subfolders hierarchy to visual studio c++ 2015 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a folder with the following hierarchy (this is just an example):

- folder1

  - file1
  - file2
  - folder2

    - file3
    - file4

If i drag and drop the folder to the project explorer all the files are added to the project without folder hierarchy, like so:

- file1
- file2
- file3
- file4

Is it even possible to add entire library (a folder hierarchy) to visual studio or is the only way to do it is manually?

Comment: Turn on "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CMake tool to do your build configurations. For example in CMakeLists.txt file, you can write as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.1)

project(name_of_your_project)

add_executable(name_of_your_project 
    src/main.cpp
    src/folder1/file1.h
    src/folder1/file1.cpp
    src/folder1/folder2/file2.h
    src/folder1/folder2/file2.cpp
 )
```

After you write above, you can use CMake tool and give your visual studio compiler configuration options. It will generate a solution file with correct folder hierarchy.

This assumes that you have a folder hierarchy as follows:

```
src
  main.cpp
  folder1
     file1.h
     file1.cpp
     folder2
       file2.h
       file2.cpp
```

For details of using CMake, see https://cmake.org/